# Sending E-Mail with attachment in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, email, smtp, attachment

I want to send a CSV file in this e-mail.
I can send the email with no problem, but I tried a lot to send attachment with it, but at the end the e-mail was sent without the attachment.

```
function sendmail($Body) {
    $Smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
    $MailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
    $Smtp.Host = "smtp-server"
    $MailMessage.From = "sender@example.com"
    $MailMessage.To.Add("recipient@example.org")
    $MailMessage.Subject = "Hello"

    $MailMessage.Body = $Body

    $smtp.Port = 25
    $smtp.EnableSsl = $false

    $Smtp.Send($MailMessage)
} 

$Body = "12334"
sendmail $Body
```

The e-mail just have to look like this:

> Hello, all the information are in the file Example.csv

Comment: How do you expect your e-mail to be sent with an attachment when you're not actually [attaching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.attachments) something? Also, PowerShell comes with the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet since v2, so unless you're stuck with v1 for some reason there should be no need to implement your own mail function.

Comment: I know that there is not any attachment in this code. but I asked if anybody have an Idea how to do it

Comment: Perhaps the link to the documentation that I specifically included in my comment could provide some clues? What do you think?

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers: there are legit reasons to make a mailer function. In my case, I needed to create attachments from variable data in memory, not disk assets, so I utilized .Net components.  As far as I know, this isn't possible with Send-MailMessage.

Answer (score 2):

`Send-MailMessage` has a direct way of handling the attachments. Below is the sample.

```cs
Send-MailMessage -From "User01 <user01@example.com>" `
                       -To "User02 <user02@example.com>", `
                           "User03 <user03@example.com>" `
                       -Subject "Sending the Attachment" `
                       -Body "Forgot to send the attachment. Sending now." `
                       -Attachment "data.csv" -SmtpServer smtp.fabrikam.com
```

OR, you should use `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage`, then you have to use:

```
$EmailFrom = "<user@domain.tld>"
$EmailTo = "<user@domain.tld>"
$EmailSubject = "<email subject"  

$SMTPServer = "smtphost.domain.tld"
$SMTPAuthUsername = "username"
$SMTPAuthPassword = "password"

$emailattachment = "<full path to attachment file.csv>"

function send_email {
    $mailmessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage 
    $mailmessage.From = ($emailfrom) 
    $mailmessage.To.Add($emailto)
    $mailmessage.Subject = $emailsubject
    $mailmessage.Body = $emailbody

    $attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($emailattachment, 'text/plain')
    $mailmessage.Attachments.Add($attachment)

    #$mailmessage.IsBodyHTML = $true
    $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 25)  
    $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("$SMTPAuthUsername", "$SMTPAuthPassword") 
    $SMTPClient.Send($mailmessage)
}
```

Refer [THIS](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/5f7a9d63-6a37-4d98-b710-d76fde920a37/how-to-get-powershell-script-to-send-email-with-attached-file?forum=winserverpowershell) if required.